# What's the point of having 'one-directional binding' (<) in Angular 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

With the introduction of components concept in Angular 1.5 one-way data binding (<) was also introduced. However, manual is saying:

> Note however, that both parent and component scope reference the same object, so if you are changing object properties or array elements in the component, the parent will still reflect that change. The general rule should therefore be to never change an object or array property in the component scope.

And indeed, changing object's property in directive/component scope gets reflected in parent scope - doesn't sound like one-directional binding, it just adds confusion to the whole thing - we're now having semi-one-directional binding, which you better do not use for objects or arrays, while for strings we have @.

What can be a useful real-case scenario of using one-way data binding? Or it is a good idea to completely avoid it in order to protect yourself against unexpected changes - since one-directional concept screams about the fact that it is one-directional, while it is not?

Comment: I have same query in this.. Do you got the answer??

Answer (score 0):

In case of `@` you should use interpolation (`{{value}}` expression) to pass some value to directive:

```
<my-directive some-value="{{value}}"></my-directive>
```

and

```
scope {
  someValue: "@"
}
```

In case of `<` binding, you set attribute value without interpolation. And when value of `value` is not `undefined`, it would be bounded with isolated scope:

```
<my-directive some-value="{{value}}"></my-directive>
```

and

```
scope {
  someValue: "<"
}
```

Of course, someValue must be a primitive, not an array or object

Comment: I understand the difference between @ and <, but what's the point of < and calling it one-directional while it's not true, and if so - the difference between < and = is like very very minimal.

Comment: true, difference between `<` and `=` its only in primitive values binding.

Comment: argh. useless and confusing, then :( was expecting truly one-directional binding. but that's probably human nature - two-way binding was such a WOW, and now I'm complaining about getting one-directional one back. :)